# Docker push command returning an 'unexpected end of JSON input' error while attempting to upload a container image to Docker Hub

Tags: dockerhub

> requested access to the resource is denied, error parsing HTTP 401 response body:unexpected end of JSON input: ""

command used:

```
docker push docker usename/image name
```

I am doing this in virtual machine on hyper v. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Message "requested access to the resource is denied" could be a cause. Try docker login <registry> before docker push. Have you tried logging in to confirm if the user has write permission?